# Can gravity cause a wave function to collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

Assume the Copenhagen interpretation.

Suppose that a particle, for example an electron, has a wavefunction. If a heavy object, like the Earth, is close by, then that object interacts with the electron by gravity. Can this interaction cause the wavefunction of the electron to collapse? Has there been any experiment in which the wavefunction collapsed by gravity alone?

Comment: _Has there been any experiment in which the wavefunction collapsed by gravity alone?_ That would win a Nobel Prize for sure. It sounds like you are interested in Objective-collapse theories. Check Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Collapse is a property a quantum interpretation can or can not have, not something we unambiguously observe. Can you, for comparison, explain how other forces like electromagnetism (or *anything* else, for that matter) "collapse" wavefunctions in your understanding and which experiments show that?

Comment: Yes, take for example double slit experiments. If there is no apparatus that observes which slit the particles go through, then we get an interference pattern. But if we measure it, then the wavefunctions of the particles collapse and the interference pattern disappears. In my understanding, the apparatus uses electromagnetism to measure the particles.

Comment: https://physicsworld.com/a/physicists-place-fresh-limits-on-gravitys-role-in-wavefunction-collapse/

Comment: I would look up gravitational decoherence.

Comment: This goes back to the issue of what actually constitutes a measurement in quantum mechanics, which is a thorny issue and depends on one's taste in interpretations.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it possible to observe. Wavefunction collapse is due to an irreversible interaction. Gravitational trajectories are a prime example of almost perfectly reversible, frictionless physics. Of course, gravity could deflect an electron wave to a detector, but we'd attribute the collapse to the irreversible detection process.

Edit:

Apparently, "gravitational decoherence" is the subject of theoretical study (thanks, @Connor Behan). Difficult to observe, though, for the reasons given above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142041/discussion-on-answer-by-john-doty-can-gravity-cause-a-wave-function-to-collapse).

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a theoretical work](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/zna-2022-0050/html?lang=en) on the wave function behavior of  neutrons in a classical gravitational field.

> Spectra of neutron wave functions in Earth’s gravitational field

It is long and involved , expected plots for checking  a running experiment are given.

[Here is an announcement](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bbe3/e60e95e9b0a79417b3d23997891391dba9d7.pdf?_ga=2.42920492.888270542.1673639047-994925074.1659585951) at a conference with experimental checks .

Look at the paragraphs "Gravity Resonance Spectroscopy
with qBOUNCE"

So the answer to your  question:"Can gravity cause a wave function to collapse" is , yes, if by "collapse one means the wavefunction to interact with the gravitational field irreversibly.

[This simplified model](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.23.236) deals with the mathematics of coherence and incoherence : Coherence versus incoherence: Collapse and revival in a simple quantum model.

> Unusual features found in the temporal behavior of this lossless model problem are "collapse," i.e., episodic nonexponential damping of both the atomic inversion and dipole moment, and two kinds of "revival" or partial recorrelation, in the dynamic evolution, during which the initial state is *nearly* recovered.

Italics mine.

The authors in the first link use this to correlate the bounce effect with data.

Comment: Interaction isn't enough: it has to be irreversible.

Comment: I think, though, I have not delved into the mathematics, the *bounce* can have  irreversible aspects.  The first link refers to https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.23.236 where the irreversibility is discussed for these type of models

Comment: This answer is complete nonsense.

Comment: @Annix it would help if you point out the nonsense in the gravitational experiments referred to? They are experiments using the newtonian gravitation as a potential in a quantum mechanical set up., and there is a "bounce" effect detected according to them. The "bounce" collapses the wavefunction and re groups it according to the links.

Comment: The nonsence is the claim that any interaction does collapse.

Comment: Changing of the form of the wave function under influence of a field is not equal to collapse at all.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. Measuring the system's sate by gravitational waves (gravitons) can cause wavefunction collapse (as we understand it). Measuring this effect is very difficult though.

Comment: Could you provide a source?

Comment: @Riemann this is just basic of quantum mechanics: any measurement by any means collapses the wave function. This a postulate in Copenhagen interpretation.

Comment: Wouldn’t that mean that the wavefunction of an electron orbiting a proton collapses immediately because of the gravitational waves coming out of the proton? But then hydrogen atoms would behave classically, which contradicts our observations

Comment: @Riemann and the same would happen also with photons, so even worse for the poor hydrogen atom.

Comment: This is a textbook example of a low-quality answer: two sentences which say “yes it can,” and a third sentence which explicitly declines to provide any supporting evidence or argument.

Comment: @Riemann gravitation field in theory is quantized as any other field. An electron orbiting a proton does not emit gravitational waves unless the atom is excited.

Comment: When it is accellerating, it does

Comment: @Riemann an electron in atom which is in its ground state does not emit any quata, electromagnetic, gravitational, or whatever. If the atom is not in ground state, it can jump to the ground state emitting energy quantum, and that can be photons or gravitons.

Comment: But even without gravitational waves: the force of gravity is still present, why doesn’t that cause wavefunction collapse?

Comment: @Riemann force? All forces are transmitted by quanta. There are no forces that have no quanta associated with them.

Comment: Thought that if two particles have a mass then there is always the gravitation force between them: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation

Comment: @Riemann yes, there is gravitation force, so what? What conclusion? There is also electromagnetic force between proton and electron.

Comment: Good point. So you mean that gravitation force does not cause collapse, but gravitational waves do. Could you provide a source for this distinction?

Comment: @Riemann measurement does, not force or waves. To do measurement you need to probe a particle with a quantum and then detect that quantum with a detector. The quantum can be photon or graviton.

Comment: But the only thing the detector does is using force and waves and interactions

Comment: @Riemann detector performs MEASUREMENT which collapses wave function. It is the fundamental concept in Copenhagen interpretation and is a postulate. If you don't like it, choose an interpretation without collapse. But you said you want an answer from Copenhagen point of view.